# Separar metodos de um component Angular 6

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-6

Olá  a todos, tenho um  component com 1266 linhas, devido ao seu grande volume de metodos, preciso separar esses metodos para facilitar uma manutenção futura, unico problema nisso é que tenho variaveis locais, e esses metodos sua grande maioria consome essas variaveis, como consigo separar esses metodos sem ter que quebrar todo meu codigo ?

Tentei criar um component Heldp, e meu component Principal passaria como parametros .

EX -- component no mesmo diretorio "MyRdesp"

```js
//ComponentPrincipal

export class ExpenseReportsFormComponent implements OnInit {

help: any; 

help = ComponentHelp

this.help.populateField(item,this) // this mandaria todo dados do meu component

}

//component que teria metodos
export class ComponentHelp{

//metodo
populateField(item:any,component:any){
// funlçoes  do meotdo 
component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].id.setValue(item.id);
          component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].currencyAlias.setValue(item.currencyAlias);
          component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].product.setValue(item.productId);
          component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].currency.setValue(item.currencyId);
          component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].productIcon.setValue(item.productIcon);
          component.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][i]['controls'].value.setValue(item.value);
}

}
```

Porem ele me da um erro dizendo que metodo não existe no ComponentHelp

Alguem poderia me dizer porque não consigo fazer este processo ? E qual a melhor forma ?

Answer (score 0):

Apos algum tempo de experiencia tive uma solução para este metodo. Não sei se esta é a melhor. Mas tratei da seguinte forma.

Crio um `component.ts` ele sera responsavel por gerenciar todo tipo de infromação que fizer necessario.

```js
export class ExpenseReportsFormComponentManager {


  public static generateForm(component: any): any {
    let itemForm = component._formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      product: [null, [Validators.required]],
      productIcon: [null],
      description: [null]
    });

    return itemForm;


  }
}
```

Este component a cima  estou deixando ele responsavel por gerar Formulario do meu website

Agora neste component princial nos instanciamos este component e toda vez que chamarmos algum metodo que pertence ao `ExpenseReportsFormComponentManager`  devemos passar por parametro `this` que sera todo nosso component, e conseguimos manipular qualquer variavelel no component principal

```js
export class ExpenseReportsFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  managerComponent: any
  this.managerComponent = ExpenseReportsFormComponentManager;
  
  this.managerComponent.generateForm(this);
}
```